# Error WIX0150: Undefined preprocessor variable when using ProjectReference against a multi-targeted project

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, wix, wix4

I have two projects: ConsoleApp1 and Package1. Both are the "empty" project templates for a net7.0 and wix4 setup project respectively.  ConsoleApp1 is modified to have `<TargetFrameworks>net7.0</TargetFrameworks>`.  Adding a project reference from Package1 and trying to access via preprocessor, binding, or otherwise the files from ConsoleApp1 is unsuccessful.

ConsoleApp1.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>net7.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Package1.wixproj

```
<Project Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk/4.0.0-rc.1">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

ExampleComponents.wxs

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ExampleComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component>
        <File Source="ExampleComponents.wxs" />
        <File Source="$(var.ConsoleApp1.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Things that don't work:

- Setting `TargetFramework` or `TargetFrameworks` in the wixproj
- Using `AdditionalProperties="TargetFramework=net7.0"` in the wixproj `ProjectReference`
- Wailing in lamentation at the barren wix4 documentation page

If I use `<TargetFramework>` instead of `<TargetFrameworks>` in the console project, the error resolves - but I need to multi-target.  How can I depend with a `ProjectReference` on a multi-targeted project with wix4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SetTargetFramework` to avoid multi-targeting in the project reference.  I'm not sure why `AdditionalProperties` fails but `SetTargetFramework` succeeds.

Updated Package1.wixproj:

```
<Project Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk/4.0.0-rc.1">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj">
      <SetTargetFramework>TargetFramework=net7.0</SetTargetFramework>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```